# Match a string in an array strpos(): Empty needle

Tags: php, arrays, session, strpos

I have a string from database that I want to match with an array but it results in error saying:

> strpos(): Empty needle in line X

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['arry'])) {
    $_SESSION['arry'] = array();
}
$imp = 42;
$arrys =  $_SESSION['arry'];

foreach($arrys as $string)
{
  if(strpos($imp, $string) !== false) 
  {
    $pow =1;
    break;
  }
}

if($pow==1){ exit; }
```

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 218
    [1] => 219
    [2] =>  218
    [3] => 220
    [4] => 222
    [5] =>  42
    [6] => 223
)
```

Comment: Swap your arguments around, i.e. `strpos($string, $imp)`

Comment: @RobbieAverill now it is not searching for the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the opposite way , searching string in 42 , instead go for

```
strpos($string, $imp)
```

**TRY THIS : (updated)**

```
<?php

    $_SESSION['arry'] = array(236,235,239,243,246);

$imp =  239;
$arrys =  $_SESSION['arry'];
$arrys = array_unique($arrys);
$pow = "";
print "<pre>";
print_r($arrys);
print "</pre>";
foreach($arrys as $string)
{
if($string == $imp)  {
    $pow = 1; echo "we have".$imp."in array<br/>";
}
else{
    $pow = 0; echo "sorry".$imp."wasn't found in array<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @SagarSingh its doing all looping under the hood . it will loop through all array objects to find if any matches value assigned to $imp

Comment: when the value of $imp was 42 it said value not found in session which is totally correct but when the value was 300 it said value found & when i echo the value there was no 300 value in session array

Comment: @SagarSingh yup because it matches by letter so 30 , 300 , 3000 , and all that gonna matchup, so  better use foreach.

Comment: @SagarSingh nice to hear i helped you , updated a bit more.

Comment: still same problem I'm sending the $imp value through ajax first time it works second time it doesn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110192/discussion-between-nirpendra-patel-and-sagar-singh).

Answer (score 2):

Just search for `$imp` in the array, no need to loop:

```
$imp = 42;
$arrys =  $_SESSION['arry'];

if(in_array($imp, $arrys)) {
    $pow = 1;
}
```

It's not clear if there is whitespace in the array elements or not, so you might need to `trim()` them:

```
in_array($imp, array_map('trim', $arrys))
```

Also, using `strpos()` you would get false positives.  If `$imp = 42` it would match `422`, `142`, `999942777`, etc.

Comment: then how to avoid it?

Comment: You use the proper tool for the job (`in_array`).  Or loop as you do and use `if($imp == $string)` or `if($imp == trim($string))`

Comment: if(in_array is working for the first $imp value on another it shows found but that value doesn't exist in session